# Function that finds maximum value in the selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code that selects a range of cells but I cannot figure out how to find the maximum value between the selected cells only.

Any idea on how to fix this? Here is what I have so far:

```
Function MaxContribution(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim max As Double


    ws.Range("$B$16:$D$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Range("D17:D1000").Select
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(activerange)

    MaxContribution = max



End Function
```

Comment: You want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: What's `activerange`? Btw - MAX still considers cells that are not visible, if that's what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Also you will not be able to pass a disjointed range, which is what you will get when using the filter, to `Max`.  You will need to iterate the areas of the range and test the max of that area against a variable that stores the current max.

Comment: is there a way for me to find the max value with only the filtered out values?

Comment: [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939)?

Comment: `max = application.Subtotal(4,ws.Range("$D$16:$D$1000"))`

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot